# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature, using moment

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I am trying to get `moment` to work in my `angular` application. Here is a clean sample [repo](https://github.com/prolink007/MomentTest) to demonstrate the issue. Clone that repo and run `ng build test-library` in the root directory. Install packages first, `npm install`.

When i try to use `moment`, i am getting the following error. What am i doing wrong? I have been trying to fix this for a while now. I have googled it many times and tried several suggestions to no avail.

Usage:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

...

  public doSomething(): string {
    const aMoment: moment.Moment = moment(); // line 22
    return aMoment.format();
  }
```

---

Error:

```
projects/test-library/src/lib/test-library.component.ts(22,36): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof moment' has no compatible call signatures.
```

---

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: have you tried importing like `import moment from "moment";`?
worked in my case

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In your case, what you're importing there is *everything* the library exports as an object called `moment`. This object obviously doesn't have a call signature as pointed out by the compiler.

According to the [type definitions](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.d.ts#L796) shipped with the library,
the default export is the moment function that you're looking to use.

Therefore, changing your import to the following should work:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Comment: I started out with this import, but that didn't work when I ran it locally, so I changed it to `import * as moment from 'moment'`, as specified by the docs. That worked locally, but gave me this same error on the build server. Why does moment behave differently locally than on a build server?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. And I solved the issue in two ways.

1)I set the value of esModuleInterop **false** under compilerOptions

```js
"esModuleInterop": false
```

2. The second way I changed the code

```js
import * as _moment from 'moment';
```

to the following code

```js
import _moment from "moment";
```

both options worked fine for my code.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fix saved me. EsModuleInterop was the villain.

Answer (score 3):

In my case

esModuleInterop:true

was there in tsconfig.json.

After removing this line, issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when Typescript compiler does not find the type definition of the methods you are using.
You need to install **@types/moment** as a dependency.

```
npm i -D @types/moment
```

Comment: according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/moment this is not necessary sinc moment provides its own types.

Comment: good to know that but the error is specific to type definition. @Arikael

Answer (score 0):

This post resolves this by changing the import from

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

to

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

[github post](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1859#issuecomment-450763924)